# How do I use tabulate with multiple named parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala

**Background**

I see examples like:

```
val squares = List.tabulate(6)(n => n * n)          // one parameter, named parameter
val mul = List.tabulate(4,5)( _ * _ )               // two parameters, unnamed parameters
```

**Question**

*What is the proper syntax for two parameters, both named?*

```
val squares = List.tabulate(3,3)(i,j => i * j - 3*j)    // two parameters, named parameters
```

gives me a `error: too many arguments for method tabulate:`, as it's interpreting the comma between `i` and `j` as an argument separator.

Comment: `val squares = List.tabulate(3,3)((i,j) => i * j - 3*j)`

Comment: See [Programming in Scala, First Edition/Functions and Closures/Short forms of function literals](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#8.4). `n => n * n` is a short form of `(n) => n * n`.

Comment: thx for the answers and references

Comment: @cloud pls repost the comment as answers to be chosen from the OP so the whole topic will be correctly recorded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scala, an anonymous function should be defined like this:

```
(x: Int, y: String, z: Long, ...) => {
  ...
} : Unit
```

First, return type can be inferred so we can omit it:

```
(x: Int, y: String, z: Long, ...) => {
  ...
}
```

Second, if the method body has only one statement, the braces can be omitted:

```
(x: Int, y: String, z: Long, ...) => ...
```

Third, if the function's parameter type can be inferred, we can omit it:

```
List(1, 2, 3).reduceLeft( (x, y) => x + y )
```

Finally, if the function's parameter type can be inferred, and there is only one parameter, then the brackets around parameter list can be omitted:

```
List(1, 2, 3).map(x => x * 2)
```

So in your case, you should write `val squares = List.tabulate(3,3)((i,j) => i * j - 3*j)`